# Using wired and wireless headphones simultaneously?

Tags: audio, headphones, bluetooth-audio

I have 1 android device, 1 wired headphones, 1 wireless headphones, 2 ppl willing to watch film. 
When I connect both of headphones only wired work.

Is it possible to use both of headphones simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

i have tried and tried, never works, either use 2 wired earphones or use 2 wireless Bluetooth earphones

Answer (score 0):

http://androidforums.com/threads/using-2-bluetooth-headsets-at-once.178052/

There are a few recommendations but this seems like it would work:
Buy a Y splitter which will turn one 3.5mm headset jack into two
Buy a Bluetooth Audio Transmitter like this one
Plug your headphones into the one Y jack
Plug your Transmitter into the other jack
Enjoy headphones + bluetooth working simultaneously
Theoretically, you could also connect 2 wired headsets or 2 bluetooth headsets with this method. This is more of a worst-case scenario hack. It seems devices with Bluetooth 4.0+ are already able to support multiple profiles:

Answer (score -2):

Use the adapter that allow to connect wired headset. The smartphone switchs automatically to the wired headphone if inserted.

Comment: Not really understood your answer... What kind of adapter do you suggest?

Comment: An adapter with one male jack and two female, to plug in the two headphones jacks, is a largely used adaptor for mp3players

Comment: I have such, but I want to use wired+wireless headphones, not wired+wired