# How to use wired and wireless headphones simultaneously?

Tags: bluetooth-audio

I have both wired and wireless headphones. I thought of sharing the both to see a movie.

To do that, can we get the audio output of both at same time.

I can able to switch the output but not access at same time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using wired and wireless headphones simultaneously?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/67081/using-wired-and-wireless-headphones-simultaneously)

Answer (score 0):

1. Upgrade to Android Pie, most of the android devices support it as an inbuilt feature since API28.
2. There are certain hacks you will find on Google for lower versions, they don't work to be honest. As per my knowledge in Pie it will work, because I'm using it